# Pointers for eBay Seller APIs?

Tags: ebay-api

I have a mobile app that allows people to upload information of clothes they have and share it with their friends. I have good traction - increasingly more users every day.

I want to create a new feature that allows users to sell unwanted items on eBay. Ideally, they'll click a button and the item will be available for sale on eBay.

I went through the developer APIs and I'm not even sure where to start. I can't tell whether I should try Retail-Standard Selling (New Sell APIs) or Traditional eBay Selling (Trading APIs) or even something else. Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're speaking of unique items I would suggest to use "old" trading API `AddFixedPriceItem`

that's made for garage-sale and can do everything with just one call. (1)

while new Sell APIs are meant for stores selling new items in multiple quantities
and requires several calls to achieve the same result (create depo, images, listing, offer...)

BUT

despite what eBay writes (that will continue to support Trading APIs)
we see that every month some Trading APIs are decommissioned or deprecated:
for example last January they removed `GetCategorySpecifics`
and for next April there will be others..

Clearly you could mix the APIs, using the best combination of both
but since you're at beginning and since the 2 API family are completely different, I suggest you to use new Sell APIs

(1) Just to create the Listing, then several other are required to find proper category, itemsSpecifics, creating the profiles.... and so on..

Comment: Many thanks! This is really helpful.

Comment: clearly this is IMHO, and on SO opinions are not welcomed since are undecided:
consider that to the same question, just 2 months ago I suggested to use old Trading API.
Anyway, if and when you'll think this was the best acceptable answer, you can  award it

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely remember that!